# Defamation/Revenge porn

Tags: criminal-law

If my ex-intimate partner decides to send our intimate/couple pictures does that count as defamation act?

If he does something like that, my relationship between me and my current boyfriend will end.

Me and my current boyfriend have been in relationship for 2 years. I heavily regret what i did. I only saw this person for 3 months in summer break, but after 6-7 months he is threatening me to leak my pictures to my current boyfriend because he found out I have a boyfriend. Between those 6-7 months he was in relationship with another women too. I had never told my intimate partner about my boyfriend but whether I tell him or not it is my decision right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If my ex-intimate partner decides to send our intimate/couple pictures does that count as defamation act?

No. It would be defamatory only if the pictures were false, forged, or to give a false impression that at some point you two got intimate. That being said, your ex-partner's conduct sounds in one or more torts and crimes unless your acts are tantamount to inviting him or challenging him to move forward.

If your ex-partner's conduct prompts your boyfriend to end the relation, most likely you would have a viable claim of *tortious interference with relation*, although it is unclear what award would remedy the situation. Your ex-partner would need to prove that his interference was *justified*. Your description nowhere reflects that he might have a valid reason to divulge the pictures.

The ex-partner might be incurring *harassment* as well, although that depends on the recent interactions between you and him, who resumed contact, and so forth. Likewise, if the ex-partner is trying to force you to do something and is using the pictures to that effect, he would incur extortion.

You might want to consider requesting a *restraining order* against your ex-partner, especially if that pattern of conduct persists.

> I had never told my intimate partner about my boyfriend but whether I tell him or not it is my decision right?

That is mostly a personal decision.

Only in special scenarios (such as contagion of some STD) that are traceable to your ex-partner, your boyfriend might have a claim against you if your boyfriend proves that your failure to make the appropriate disclosure constitutes *gross negligence* that caused him damages. The questions would be (1) whether timely disclosure would have prompted your boyfriend to take precautions, and (2) whether his reliance on you[r silence] was reasonable. However, that is applicable to all relations and not just to the stressful situation you describe.

Comment: From the Wikipedia article on tortuous interference it seems to be about business relationships, not intimate relationships.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I agree there might be a more precise term for torts causing non-business, personal type of injury just like [*Wyatt v. McDermott*, 725 S.E.2d 555 (2012)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/invaco20120420d53) acknowledges "*tortious interference with parental rights*" as a cause of action (similarly, "*t.i. with an expectancy of inheritance*"). But labels like "*loss of consortium*" and "*intentional infliction of emotional distress*" seem inapplicable and/or needlessly stringent. The *prima facie* elements for OP's matter ultimately are equivalent to "*t.i. with business*", though.

Comment: other than it has nothing to do with commerce/business

Comment: In CA     1. An economic relationship that was likely to benefit the plaintiff;
    2. The defendant’s knowledge of this relationship;
   3.  Wrongful conduct by the defendant;
   4.  Intent on the defendant’s part to disrupt the economic relationship, or knowledge that disruption was likely because of their conduct;
    5. Disruption of the relationship;
    6. Harm to the plaintiff; and
   7.  A causal connection between the wrongful act and the harm.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite "*other than it has nothing to do with commerce/business*". Exactly. The OP's loss would be in the form of --at least-- *intangible damages* akin to *lost companionship* and *mental anguish*, consistent with *Wyatt at 563* (there being no economic relationship in a context of parental rights). The label in the OP's pleadings (be it *relation*, *companionship*, etc.) will matter very little as long as these reflect the ex-partner's pattern of conduct and its effects on the OP's environment.

Comment: From what I see such a pleading would not have a key required element (economic disruption)as per the CA statue, for example. Can a tort pleading be free form without regard to the elements in a related statute?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite "*From what I see such a pleading would not have a key required element*". But not all torts require an element of economic nature. Also, many torts are premised on common law rather than legislation. The *Wyatt* decision illustrates this point: Parenthood is definitely not an economic relationship, *tortious interference with parental rights* has no statutory basis (see *Wyatt at 558*), and yet the tort is a valid cause of action (there being case law that outlines the distinctive elements of that tort as *Wyatt* does at 562).